# Magento 2: getting Full Action name?

Tags: magento2

Would you please let me know best way to get the Full Action name inside custom Model class in Magento 2?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the `Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` interface in your constructor (by default it should return an instance of the  `Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` class), and then use it as follows:

```php
// considering the http://localhost/mage242/customer/account/login url
echo $request->getRouteName() . '<br />';         //customer
echo $request->getModuleName() . '<br />';        //customer
echo $request->getControllerName() . '<br />';    //account
echo $request->getActionName() . '<br />';        //login
echo $request->getFullActionName() . '<br />';    //customer_account_login
echo $request->getControllerModule() . '<br />';  //Magento_Customer
```

*Vote this answer up if it helps.*

Comment: This answer works like a charm.

Comment: Is it deprecated to use object manager in magento2?

Comment: It's not deprecated, but its use is completely discouraged due to the side effects @sameerkhan